# Error while getting the process id

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a clipboard monitor as a project and on clipboard change the application detects which program has used the clipboard by calling the GetClipboardOwner.

This is an excerpt from the code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
            const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                    Debug.Indent();
                    //Process the clipboard here
                    uint processId;
                    IntPtr ownerHwnd = GetClipboardOwner();
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(ownerHwnd, out processId);
                    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId);
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Window Title: {0} Filename: {1}", proc.MainWindowTitle, process.MainModule.FileName));
                    SendMessage(_NextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    break;

                case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                    if (m.WParam == _NextClipboardViewer)
                        _NextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                    else
                        SendMessage(_NextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    break;

                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and the DLLImports:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr _newviewerhandle);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr removehandle, IntPtr nexthandle);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetClipboardOwner();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out uint threadid);
```

Exception in Output window is - A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in Something.exe

**UPDATE 2** After changing "Kernel32" to "User32", it works but for some applications like Word, Excel, I get this exception; A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 3** The above exception was caused due to a 32-bit process (my application) accessing the module of a 64-bit process (Word, Excel, etc.)
Changing the configuration to x64 worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DllImport` for `GetWindowThreadProcessId` should use `user32.dll`, not `kernel32.dll`

Per MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx

Or simply use PInvoke.Net: [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good call.  I forgot about that site :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Now, I feel silly and embarrassed about that.
Now, I'm getting another error...updating the question

Comment: @vs2010noob Hi, this is now a different question.  The exception you get now is very different from the original  (EntryPointNotFoundException and Win32Exception).  I'd suggest marking this question as answered and opening up the Win32Exception problem a new question.

Comment: Alright :) Thanks for your help.
I solved the exception too, updated the question.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Interesting resolution on the Win32Exception!